# NodeJs - include HTML file by using the filesystem

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am new to web programming and started learning NodeJs. I created a new project just for testing and learning. This is the projects structure

[image: Project]

My **Server.js** contains this code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fileSystem = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var page = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

  fileSystem.readFile(getPage(page), null, function(error, data){
    if(error){
      throw error;
    } else {
      res.writeHead(data);
    }
    res.end();
  })
});
server.listen(2312);

function getPage(page){
  var content = "Templates/";
  switch (page) {
    case "/Page1":
        content += 'Page1.html';
        break;
    case "/Page2":
        content += 'Page2.html';
        break;
    case "/Page3":
        content += 'Page3.html';
        break;
    default:
        content += 'Page404.html';
    }
    return content;
}
```

My **html files** contain very simple HTML code

Page1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Button.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Btns.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="loadPage2()">Load Page 2</button>

  <button onclick="loadPage3()">Load Page 3</button>

</body>

</html>
```

So when trying `http://localhost:2312/Page1` I get an invalid status code of 0.

> _http_server.js:195
>       throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
>       ^
>
> RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
>       at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:195:11)
>       at ...\TestProjekt\Server.js:13:9
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:439:3)

Is it possible to load html files by doing this way?

I know I could use the **Express framework** but I thought about learning and starting with the native code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `res.writeHead(data);` to `res.write(data);`

`writeHead()` Sends a response header to the request.

`write()` Sends data.

The first time `response.write()` is called, it will send the buffered header information and the first chunk of the body to the client. The second time `response.write()` is called, Node.js assumes data will be streamed, and sends the new data separately.

Comment: or just res.end(data)

Comment: when doing this, the code works fine but the console says `Unexpected token <` so the linked js file is not linked correctly? ..

Comment: You have no routes, to any javascript files.. So how can it load them?.  maybe `case "/Btns.js": content += 'Btns.js'; break;` to solve.

Comment: Ah yes. Just placed the js and css file in the same directory as the templates files. But the error still remains.

Comment: even though you have a script tag in your html, the browser still makes a request of the server for that .js file. you need to handle that request and serve the Btns.js file when it is requested

Comment: how can I serve this file by request?

Answer (score 0):

**var readSream = fs.createReadStream('index.html','utf8')**

**readSream.pipe(response);**

```
 var http = require('http');
   var fs = require('fs');

  http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    var readSream = fs.createReadStream('index.html','utf8')
    readSream.pipe(response);
  }).listen(3000);

 console.log("server is running on port number ");
```

Comment: you absolutely can serve files without making a stream.

Comment: You can do it the way the OP has mentioned, but I would say Streams are a good idea too, especially if you end up sending images etc.  Not sure you deserved a down-vote though..  In fact I've up-voted, as I think it's a good idea to point out the streams way..

Comment: i'll remove my downvote if the answer is edited to reflect the OPs way can work, a fix for it, and then the preferred way of streaming. this just isn't a very good answer as it doesn't give much help to the OP, who is new to node